# Chrome URL resolution

Tags: networking, google-chrome

I have an entry in /etc/hosts associating "artifactory" to its IP.
When I do "ping artifactory" it pings the IP.

But when I type : "http://artifactory:8081" in Chrome, it goes every time to https://www.artifactory.com/.

What I've tried so far :

- Clear all caches except passwords
- Disable the 2 Chrome WS susceptible to alter the URL :

  - "Utiliser un service Web pour résoudre les erreurs de navigation"
  - "Utiliser un service de prédiction afin de compléter les recherches et les URL saisies dans la barre d'adresse"
- When I go to chrome://dns, I can read : DNS pre-resolution and TCP pre-connection is disabled.
- In chrome://net-internals/#dns I've clicked "Clear cache".

What else could I try ?

Comment: Hint : it may be related to the use of a corporate proxy, because the phenomenon stops when I disable it, but why doesn't it fail saying "artifactory not found" instead of rewriting my URL ? which layer is rewriting the URL ?

Comment: So yeah, just don’t use the proxy? Or perhaps use Firefox but don’t set up a proxy there. // That being said, you can use Developer Tools to find out why it’s redirecting somewhere. On the “Network” tab, check “Preserve log” and then try again.

Comment: Ok, I try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After watching the network logs as suggested, I get it : it does the same thing with Firefox. It's not Chrome or Firefox rewriting my URL, it's a proxy resolution which leads to a redirection (HTTP 302) to www.artifactory.com